# Get image src onClick react

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying to print image src with the help of `e.target.src` to get the output as 'Person-1.jpg' but instead getting as 'localhost:3000/static/media/Person-1.bb56f19f.png'

```
const imageSrc = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.src);
}

<img src={require('directory').default} onClick={imageSrc}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log(e.target.getAttribute('src'));`

`.src` returns the URL.

`.getAttribute('src'));` returns the source parameter as it is.

Comment: Still returns "/static/media/Person-1.bb56f19f.png"

Comment: I got a new thing, I have an image named 'blank_profile.png' and when I click it for e.target.src it returns something as "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAVQA…", any solution for this to return to normal image name ?

Answer (score 0):

If the format is uniform, you can just process the string like so:

```
// Let's say the e.target.src is "localhost:3000/static/media/Person-1.bb56f19f.png"
const baseString = e.target.src

// Split the string by "/" to return:
// ["localhost:3000", "static", "media", "Person-1.bb56f19f.png"]
// Then pop to get the last value of the array, which is:
// "Person-1.bb56f19f.png"
const fileName = baseString.split('/').pop()

// Then split the filename by "." to return
// ["Person-1", "bb56f19f", "png"]
// Then use a template strign to append the new format with the
// first element of the previous array
const actualFileName = `${fileName.split('.')[0]}.jpg`

// Should be "Person-1.jpg"
console.log(actualFileName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hack, only if react does not have an in built function.